# PDF of GitHub Readme file

Tags: github, pdf, file-conversion

Is there a way to download the Readme file of a GitHub project as a PDF, with the same formatting as the readme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the **RAW** link of that `README.md` file.

Then go to [web2pdfconvert](http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/).

Paste link and click **Convert to PDF**.

Download your PDF.